# Problem with block helpers and JavaScript templates after Rails 3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application I'm upgrading from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3 that uses a combination of helpers and JavaScript templates that is not working after the upgrade. I have the following code in a view partial:

```
  <%= content_for :jstemplates do -%>
  <%= "var serviceoverride='#{generate_template(customer_form, :serviceoverrides).html_safe}'" %>
  <%= "var clientimage='#{generate_template(customer_form, :customer_images).html_safe}'" %>
  <%= "var formula='#{generate_template(customer_form, :formulas).html_safe}'" %>
  <% end -%>
```

That calls a generate_template helper:

```
def generate_template(form_builder, method, options = {})
  escape_javascript generate_html(form_builder, method, options)
end

def generate_html(form_builder, method, options = {})
  options[:object] ||= form_builder.object.class.reflect_on_association(method).klass.new
  options[:partial] ||= method.to_s.singularize
  options[:form_builder_local] ||= :f  

  form_builder.fields_for(method, options[:object], :child_index => 'NEW_RECORD') do |f|
    render(:partial => options[:partial], :locals => { options[:form_builder_local] => f })
  end
end
```

And the view partial is rendered from one of the standard controller views. The problem is that the JavaScript output on the rendered page is always HTML escaped and thus is directly rendered on the page. This worked correctly in Rails 2.3.x and obviously broke in Rails 3, I suspect with the change in behavior of <% %> block style helpers.

My problem is that I cannot get the jstemplates to render unescaped. I've looked into the changes in block style helpers and tried ensuring that all content generating blocks are using <%= %>, using the <%=raw %> function, adding .html_safe to strings and so on. It seems like I'm missing something basic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I apparently had the raw blocks in the wrong place. This change fixed it:

```
<%= content_for :jstemplates do -%>
  <%=raw "var serviceoverride='#{generate_template(customer_form, :serviceoverrides).html_safe}'" %>
  <%=raw "var clientimage='#{generate_template(customer_form, :customer_images).html_safe}'" %>
  <%=raw "var formula='#{generate_template(customer_form, :formulas).html_safe}'" %>
<% end -%>
```